# Android crashes with Intent.createChooser(Intent,title) because of facebook messenger :Service not registered

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent

```
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked ServiceConnection ActivityInfo{6ca8053 com.facebook.messenger.intents.ShareIntentHandler} that was originally bound here

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ActivityInfo{6ca8053 com.facebook.messenger.intents.ShareIntentHandler}
```

I tried solving this in different ways available over Stack Overflow but no help.

It is working perfectly on Android V below 6.0 (M). On 6.0, the app get crashed.

It is working first time but the issue occurs on clicking/trying to launch intent chooser second time.

Comment: did you just tried starting intent normally via startActivity() for android version 6?

Comment: @HasifSeyd: Yes, I had tried that and it was working fine but with startActivity(),  I was not getting the better UI of application chooser along with list of people I had recently had conversation with.

Comment: This issue was reported in Android 6.0 marshamallow version, and was provided with patch by google. maybe the device which you tried was not updated properly by this patch by that particular vendor, so you don't have to worry, you can for time-being use workaround for this issue by checking the version and then starting the activity accordingly